# Who pays for the storage on smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Here is a smart contract from the official tutorial

```
contract MyToken {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    }
}
```

This has a `mapping`. It is impossible to tell in advance how many entries are going to be added to this mapping.

How is the miner compensated for the amount of storage used by this contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fixed cost in a unit called `gas` for each 32 bytes that is added to storage. This must be supplied by the user sending the transaction. When running the transaction, if it tries to use more gas than the user has supplied, an exception is thrown and the transaction reverted, except for the gas funds already used which are deducted from the user's balance.

Funds spend on storage are partially refunded if and when the stored data is deleted.

You only need to pay for gas when you store data. There have been discussions about whether you should be charged additionally for continuing to use storage, but there is no concrete plan to do this at present.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy contract you need to pay trans fee. Because creation of contract is also recorded as a tras in Eth.

Coming to original qus Who is calling your contract method he(user/owner) will pay for that.

Transaction cost is nothing but (storage + computation steps) * gasPrice.

This fee is paid by person who call the method.

Coming to storage, eth will charge cost for only current change in the storage. It will not charge money for all previous data.

Say for eg: if you have 100 previous data blocks if you want to insert new  data block, EVM will compute gas consumption for current input data.

Total transaction fee = gas * gasPrice;

In general Gas is a EVM execution step's, so while writing code needs to be careful.

So you no need to worry about total fee.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Contracts, the account doing so pays for the deployment Gas. when calling contract methods the caller has to send some amount of gas with each call, which will be given to the miners upon mining the block which the transaction is stored.

What you asked about poses no difference, adding some value to a mapping in a deployed contract provokes the same mechanism of payment as a regular method call if the adding is not coming from a method.

Answer (score 0):

The cost is 3200 gas to deploy the smart contract plus an additional of 200 gas for each byte of source code